# Running all tests for a multi-binary project

Tags: unit-testing, go, structure, project-structure, go-testing

Consider a multi binary project with the following structure.

```
.
├── bin1
│   ├── config
│   │   ├── config.go
│   │   └── config_test.go
│   └── utils
│       ├── utils.go
│       └── utils_test.go
├── bin2
│   ├── config
│   │   ├── config.go
│   │   └── config_test.go
│   └── utils
│       ├── utils.go
│       └── utils_test.go
├── cmd
│   ├── bin1
│   │   └── bin1.go
│   ├── bin2
│   │   └── bin2.go
│   └── bin3
│       └── bin3.go
├── go.mod
├── go.sum
└── shared
    ├── db
    │   ├── db.go
    │   └── db_test.go
    ├── model
    │   ├── modela.go
    │   ├── modela_test.go
    │   ├── modelb.go
    │   └── modelb_test.go
    └── utils
        ├── utils.go
        └── utils_test.go
```

This project has three binaries `bin1`, `bin2` and `bin3`. Packages in the `/shared` directory (e.g. package `shareddb`, `sharedmodel` and `sharedutils`) are shared with binary specific packages (e.g. package `bin1config`, `bin1utils` in `/bin1` directory and package `bin2config`, `bin2utils` in `/bin2` directory).

How can we run

- all the unit tests in this project altogether?
- all the tests in a package (e.g. in `shared/model`)?
- each tests separately?

I attempted the following.

- Running `go test` from the project root resulted in `no Go files in /projectroot`.

Answer (score 2):

```bash
# run all tests
go test ./...

# run all tests under a specific directory (including subdiretories)
go test ./bin2/...

# test package located in specific directory
go test ./shared/model

# test package that has specific import path
go test projectroot/shared/model

# test package in current working directory
go test

# ditto
go test .

# test package in parent directory
go test ..

# run a specific test within the package under test
go test -run=X

# run a specific sub-test within the package under test
go test -run=X/Y
```

For more details on the `go test` command, see [Test packages](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Test_packages).

For more details on the `[packages]` argument to `go test`, see [Packge lists and patters](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Package_lists_and_patterns).

For more details on the testing flags, see [Testing flags](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Testing_flags).